# Calling an external web service to populate Dynamic Data Dropdown Component

Tags: rest, dynamic, get, dropdown, orbeon

I'm trying to call a web service to complete the list of items in a Dynamic Data Dropdown Component.
I'm following the [get submission page](http://wiki.orbeon.com/forms/doc/developer-guide/processors-xforms-submission#TOC-GET-example).
I've created an xpl:

```html
<p:config xmlns:p="http://www.orbeon.com/oxf/pipeline"
   ...">

<p:param type="input" name="instance" />
<p:param type="output" name="data" />
 
<p:processor name="oxf:xforms-submission">
  <p:input name="submission">
    <xforms:submission method="get" action="myURL"/>
  </p:input>
  <p:input name="request">
    <parameters>
   <param1>admin</param1>
   <param2>password</param2>
    </parameters>
  </p:input>
  <p:output name="response" id="response"/>
</p:processor>

</p:config>
```

Then I call it in my form. When I try the form I see this error in orbeon.log

> Fatal error: The prefix "xforms" for element "xforms:submission" is not bound.

Am I missing something?

Comment: Do you define `xmlns:xforms="http://www.w3.org/2002/xforms"` anywhere?

Comment: No, I copied the xpl from one of the services available (zip-states)
Should that be in the config tag? What does this sentence do?

Comment: In XML, namespace prefixes must always have a namespace mapping. You can put it on the root element of the XML pipeline, for example `<p:config xmlns:p="http://www.orbeon.com/oxf/pipeline" xmlns:xforms="http://www.w3.org/2002/xforms">`.

Comment: @Bruno And the `..."` on the second line of your source is incorrect. If you're not already doing so, I'd recommend you use XML-aware editor, as it will tell you about that type of errors without you having to then "spot" them.

Comment: @ebruchez it's working fine with the mapping of xforms, thanks! avernet sorry I didn't mention, the "..." where to avoid pasting all the mappings, I thought they weren't important.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In XML, namespace prefixes must always have a namespace mapping. You can put it on the root element of the XML pipeline, for example

```html
<p:config xmlns:p="http://www.orbeon.com/oxf/pipeline" xmlns:xforms="http://www.w3.org/2002/xforms">
```